# doctype and onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

could someone please explain why the following code, where I simply move a div to mouse click position, does work only if I remove the DOCTYPE tag ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Prova</title>
    <style>
      .bbox{
        width: 10px;
        height:10px;
        position:absolute;
        background-color: orange;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onclick = "moves()">
   <script>
       function moves(){
       var cordx;
       var cordy;
       var d;
       var e = window.event;
       d= document.getElementById('box');
       cordx = e.clientX;
       cordy = e.clientY;
       d.style.left = cordx;
      d.style.top = cordy;

    }
  </script>



<div class="bbox" id='box'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS requires that [lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units) (other than `0`) have units.

You are assigning integers to `d.style.left` and `d.style.top`.

If you [forget the Doctype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes) then the browser assumes the page was written in the 90s and [emulates the bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) that browsers of that era had. Once such bug is treating an integer in CSS as a pixel value instead of an error.

Use `+ "px"`.